# Pytest coverage with line coverage and minimum limits like karma/Istanbul

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, code-coverage, karma-coverage, pytest-cov

1. In Instanbul coverage module for Karma you can set thresholds for different kind of coverages. If some coverage doesnt meet its minimum then instanbul throws an error. This is very usefull when building the project with jenkins and you have to keep such limits. Is it possible to get similar functionality with pytest-cov or any other module?

https://ibb.co/y4J3JrG

2. pytest-cov generates only statements coverage. Is it possible to get line/code coverage as well?

Answer (score 1):

Coverage.py (which is the engine for pytest-cov) has thresholds for total coverage, but not separate thresholds for different measurements.  Look at the `--fail-under` option.

Coverage.py can measure statement coverage and branch coverage.  You mention "line" coverage and "code" coverage: I don't know how those differ from statement coverage.

Comment: Thanks for response. Well, i found out that statement coverage is not the same as line because there are many languages with EOL marks which can have more than one statement in line f.ex. x = 4 ; y = x  + 10;. But python offcourse cant do that so we can assume that statements = lines. However still dont know how to show precentage in branches coverage. I just see number in TOTAL branches but how much are they covered? I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the option you need as follows:

> pytest --help

--cov-fail-under=MIN  Fail if the total coverage is less than MIN.